# When asking users to stop using ad block for the site, what percentage are expected to comply?

Tags: google-adsense, adblock

[30% of desktop users block ads in the USA](https://www.statista.com/statistics/804008/ad-blocking-reach-usage-us/)

I'm guessing it is probably higher in my niche since I'm making a game and gamers are closer to the early adopter segment.

When some sites *politely* ask me to stop ad blocking if I want to support their site, I do it, if I'm a fan of the site. So I am curious what % of my players would stop ad blocking if I asked and to estimate that I'm seeking to learn what results others have seen.

Note that I don't plan on blocking the content. I'm considering politely asking them.

Comment: I have no idea where to find this data. Some sites may have a tracking metric for users that were asked to disable their ad blocking, but I'm not sure if any have made the data public. I have to imagine the vast majority of ad blocking users will not stop blocking ads unless the site suppresses their content.

Comment: I just polled myself and found that I don't stop using ad blockers when asked.   Extrapolating from my sample size of 1, nobody will disable their ad blockers for you.

Comment: Like you, if I am a fan of the site then I _might_ unblock the site. However, I imagine the overall percentage of site visitors that would do this would be very low. I suppose a comparable metric (that would be even lower) would be: "How many users donate?". However, I imagine this would be very subjective and vary considerably per site/product.

Comment: I expanded on the research by @StephenOstermiller and a sample of 2 respondents show that 100% of people will NOT unblock an ad blocker no matter how politely they are asked.  Based on my personal sample of 1, people will find another site, it is pretty unusual for a site to have unique content that isn't available anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to offer 2 options for your website?

1. a "free" site with ads, or
2. "ad free" for a fee.

This seems to be becoming an industry standard. Is that doable for you? Would that solve the problem, or would people still be able to block the advertisements?

 I suppose that's more questions than answer... just an audible thought.